# HandlebarsJS - {{#each}} statement with 2 strings

Tags: handlebars.js

Is it possible to do this?

```
{{#each not categorized}}
    <p>blablab</p>
{{/each}}
```

or do I have to do something like

```
{{#each not_categorized}}
    <p>blablab</p>
{{/each}}
```

Because when I use the first option, nothing gets displayed!?

My JSON returns:

```
{
  "not categorized": [
    { .... }
  ],

  "live": [
    {....}
  ],

  "others": [
    {....}
  ]
}
```

It works when I do:

```
{{#each live}}
  ....
{{/each}
```

What is the issue here?

thanks in advance...

Comment: I guess it would require you to write your own "not" helper. You can maybe try and use the built-in http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals one

Comment: @mfirry thanks for the tip! where do I place such a helper? in the html template itself?

Comment: It really depends on the stack you're using for your "thing". I would put it outside of the template and then I would add a <script src="WHATEVER/handlebars-helper.js"></script> or something like that

Comment: I use the `HandlebarsJS` within a `BackboneJS`- application and `RequireJS`... so do I have to place it inside the relevant view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access using  brackets []

```
{{#each [not categorized]}}
    <p>blablab</p>
{{/each}}
```

You can use it in combinations with dot notation if you need to access sub objects.